# Not highlighting the button in navabr after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using font-awesome and bootstrap and I have this in my menu:

```
<li><a href="/help/index.htm" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a></li>
```

and I looked around the `CSS` and this was the part affecting the color:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006687;
}
```

the problem is when I click on that link, it opens my help page in a new tab which is fine BUT now the Help button remains in that selected focus color until I click somewhere else on the form. I thought removing the `a:focus` part and just leaving the `a:hover` part will fix it but it didn't . 
What else should I do?

Comment: Removing `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus` from the css worked for me, so the problem is elsewhere. Edit: hmm, after testing it with an existing page, the link stays hovered as well, you might have to refocus the original page with javascript, since ity seems the mouse is still considered to be over the element once you return to that tab.

Comment: @Shilly yes that'a the problem. Can you help with JS side? I don't know much JS

Comment: @Bohn did you tried my jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to remove the `a:focus` part, but to **overwrite** it:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  // here comes your default stance, for example:
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #337ab7;
}
```

Comment: This is the exact copy of my answer

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Sorry, but your jsfiddle didn't work for me in the moment of answering the question.

Comment: You can clearly see that this answer is edited 14 minutes ago and i have write that color in the answer at least 18 minutes ago when you asked. So it's clearly that it's totally a copied answer :)

Comment: Eh okay, and when did you edit your jsfiddle? But it's okay, no need for me to fight for simple CSS snippets.

Comment: the asnwer as there because we can see the time when you have make the coment in my answer because you asked my for the color and i haven't changed anymore that answer. But this answer here is changed 2 minutes after you have make the comment in my answer. we are not fighting man i just wanted to know why you choose a copy as correct :)

Comment: My friend, I didn't chose anything. I just wrote the explicit answer on his problem mentioning the background-color. Please don't flame me.

Comment: I had that for the guy who choose your answer as correct sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3bo9q29/23/) for that :)

```
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
   text-decoration:none;
   color: #337ab7;
 }
```

Comment: where did you get that color number from? it is different

Comment: Your color for a element is that one before it's clicked. You can use your browser developer tools to get that :)